# Controlling Camera Rotations Using PCLVisualizer

Tags: camera, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**PCLVISUALIZER.CAMERA_** QUESTIONS ...
Given: camera_ with values clip:0,0, focal:0,0,0, pos:0,0,0, view:0,0,0 ....
Rotate camera_ to point in the direction: (1, .75, -2)....
Rotate the camera to aim to the left (x direction) 45 degrees relative to its current setting.

What are the formulas for PCLVisualizer.camera_ rotations?

Is there a relationship between quaternions and these four attributes?

What do each of these settings represent?

Right now I have crude approximations of ways to rotate the camera and translate it, but I have not figured out how to aim the camera based on a direction vector. Help would be tremendous...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10300/controlling-camera-rotations-using-pclvisualizer/) by [chrlz](https://answers.ros.org/users/588/chrlz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should probably be asked on the pcl-users mailing list; it's very active, you'll probably get a quick response.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1